# Prove that if $12a+6b+4c+3d=0$, then $a+bx+cx^2+dx^3=0$ has a real solution in $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers such that $12a+6b+4c+3d=0$.

Prove that $a+bx+cx^2+dx^3=0$ has a real solution in $(0,1)$.

Note : I have no idea ! How is the assumption even related to the statement that the question wants us to prove? I don't understand.

Second Note ( Edited ) : I know that if $x$ is too large, the equation goes to $+\infty$ and when $x$ is so much below $0$, the equation goes to $-\infty$. Then we can apply mean value theorem and say there exists some point such that on that point, the equation becomes zero. It's ok. But **how to show that the root is in $(0,1)$ and what is the use of knowing $12a+6b+4c+3d=0$?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A cubic with real coefficients always has at least one real solution, so you need only about the case where $d=0$ (and $c\not=0$).

Comment: @BarryCipra i don't know about the theorem you're using

Comment: @TinaAshtiani I believe the theorem is called the leading coefficient test

Comment: The intermediate value theorem is used on the continuous function $f(x) = a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3$.

Comment: @GFauxPas well, we didn't learn it on the class ... so i can't use it

Comment: Every cubic equation (1), $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx +d = 0$, with real coefficients and $a$ ≠ 0, has three solutions (some of which may equal each other if they are real, and two of which may be complex non-real numbers) and at least one real solution r1 : Wikipedia

Comment: So you just set $|x|$ sufficiently large, say $$x = \frac{|a|+|b|+|c|}{|d|+1}$$ to conclude the leading coefficient test.

Comment: Now put $d=0$ and solve it.

Comment: @S.H.W i truely appreciate your help. But can u please say that how is knowing the first assumption useful ?

Comment: @TinaAshtiani The condition is strange and unnecessary, which is why you're not getting a useful answer. Can you tell us where the problem came from? Is there any missing context? Are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: @EthanBolker real analysis a first course russell gordon . Questions of section 4.4 ... the first question

Comment: @TinaAshtiani Please read my answer.

Comment: Use Rolle's Theorem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out that $12a+6b+4c+3d=0$ is the condition that makes Rolle's Theorem applicable. Let 
$$ f(x)=\int_0^x(a+bt+ct^2+dt^3)dt=ax+\frac b2x^2+\frac b3x^3+\frac d4x^4.$$
Then clearly $f(x)$ is continuous in $[0,1]$, differentiable in $(0,1)$, $f(0)=0$, and
$$f(1)=a+\frac b2+\frac b3+\frac d4=\frac{1}{12}(12a+6b+4c+3d)=0.$$ By Rolle's Theorem, there is $\xi\in(0,1)$ such that $f'(\xi)=0$, namely $a+bx+cx^2+dx^3=0$ has a root in $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 3):

We know Every cubic equation $dx^3+cx^2+bx+a=0$
with real coefficients and $d\not= 0$ has three solutions (some of which may equal each other if they are real, and two of which may be complex non-real numbers) and at least one real solution. So now we put $d=0$ and we get :
$$cx^2+bx+a=0$$ 
and
 $$12a + 6b+ 4c =0 \to 6a+3b+2c = 0 \to b = \frac{6a+2c}{-3}$$
 Now we want to $\Delta_1 \ge0$ ( to has real root).

$\Delta_1 = b^2-4ac = \frac{36a^2+4c^2+24ac}{9} - 4ac = \frac{36a^2+4c^2-12ac}{9}\ge0\iff 9a^2-3ac+c^2\ge0$

Which it is obvious because $\Delta_2 = -27a^2c^2\le0$

Note : When $\Delta \lt 0 $ quadratic polynomial has same sign as coefficient of $x^2$.(In this case 9) and if $\Delta = 0$ value of quadratic polynomial will be zero at one point and in other points has same sign as coefficient of $x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things that might help guide you in the right direction:

Let $f(x)$ = $a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$

If $d\neq 0$ :

1) Is $f$ continuous?

2) What is $\lim_{x\to \infty}$$f(x)$? What is $\lim_{x\to -\infty}$$f(x)$?

3) What do we know about the signs of the above two limits, and what can this tell us about the existence of a zero/root?

If $d=0$ , $f$ has degree $\leq2$

How can we show a quadratic (or linear) function has a zero/root?

Comment: I understand what you're saying ... but doesn't it seem so simple ? what's the use of $12a+6b+4c+3d=0$ ?

Comment: Read my comment.

Comment: If you are asking whether the consequence of the Intermediate Value Theorem seems so simple/obvious, then you are not alone in thinking that.  It does seem intuitive that if you have a continuous function that is at some point negative and at another point positive, that there must be a point in between the two such that f is 0 at that point.

Comment: The additional constraint essentially says that perhaps d=0 (and maybe the other coefficients are zero as well).  In the case that d is 0 but c is not 0, we cannot guarantee the existence of a zero using the argument we did for the cubic.  This is because the end behavior of a quadratic has the same sign for both ends.

Comment: If $d=0$, then $12f(\pm\frac1{\sqrt 3})=12a\pm 4\sqrt 3 b+4c=(\pm 4\sqrt 3-6)b$, one is $>0$, one is $<0$ (or both are $=0$)